# Sharing AWS s3 object in Inertia

Tags: reactjs, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, inertiajs

I am working on a single page application using Inertia-react. I have an image stored in a private AWS s3 bucket. I want to display this image in my layout on multiple Inertia pages .

So, I shared the image in the HandleInertiaRequests.php  and used it in a react component as  below.

HandleInertiaRequests.php

```
public function share(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'auth' => [
            'user' => $request->user(),
        ],
        'ziggy' => function () use ($request) {
            return array_merge((new Ziggy)->toArray(), [
                'location' => $request->url(),
            ]);
        },
        'picture' => fn () => $request->user() ? 
            Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl('images/users/'.$request->user()->picture, '+2 minutes') :
            null,
    ]);
}
```

UserPicture.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

export default function UserPicture({ className }) {
    const src = usePage().props.picture;
    
    return (
        <>
            <img className={className} src={src} alt="user picture"></img>
        </>
    );
}
```

Everything works fine except that the image reloads when I navigate through the inertia pages sharing the same layout. How can I avoid this undesired behavior? One thing I noticed, this reloading doesn't happen for example when I display  `<p>{auth.user.name}</p>` instead of img in the UserPicture component.